# SQL - Pulling everything after last forward slash

Tags: spotfire

I'm trying to pull the string to the right of the last forward slash in the string below.

```
/Applied Analytics/URMFG/Service Analysis/ServiceAnalysis
```

So basically, I would like to see `ServiceAnalysis` returned.

I've come across the following SQL, which is close to what I need, but it's not exact.

```
=MID(K19, FIND("/",K19)+1, LEN(K19))
```

Comment: That looks like an Excel formula. :) Are you sure it's SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular Expressions to the rescue! you can achieve this using the `RXReplace()` function:

```
RXReplace([column],"^/.*/(.*)$","$1","")
```

I'll let you look up the `RXReplace()` documentation on your own, but just to explain the regex itself:

`^/` matches the beginning of the string and the starting /

`.*/` matches any characters that come next, followed by a / which is the final / before the end of the string (and preceeding the bit that we want to extract)

`(.*)$` matches any characters that come next, putting them into a "capturing group" (basically a variable), followed by the end of the string

the `$1` is a token which refers to the capturing group above (normally this looks like `\1` in regex, but Spotfire is a bit different)

pretty much any time you need to deal with extracting bits of strings in Spotfire expressions, `RXReplace()` is what you want. it's a lot more sustainable than doing a ton of `Left()`s, `Right()`s, and `Len()`s, although the initial effort can be a bit higher.

more regex info at http://www.regular-expressions.info/.

Comment: Niko!!  You are amazing, it works perfectly now. Thank you so much for the quick reply!  Thank you to everyone who tried to help before I specified, and I apologize for using this incredible resource so lackluster initially.  I will be sure to be more specific next time I have a question.

Comment: is it supported in SQL server?

Comment: this is a function from the Spotfire Expression Language, but SQL Server probably has its own regex matching function.

Answer (score 6):

```
DECLARE @test NVARCHAR(100)
SET @test = '/Applied Analytics/URMFG/Service Analysis/ServiceAnalysis'

SELECT REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@test), CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@test)) -1))
```

Reverse the String and find first instance of  /

Find characters to the left of /

Reverse again to get your desired result

Answer (score 5):

In SQL, you could do this:

```
declare @string varchar(100) = '/Applied Analytics/URMFG/Service Analysis/ServiceAnalysis';

select RIGHT(@string,charindex('/',reverse(@string),1)-1)
```

However, still waiting to see if it's EXCEL you're referencing (since that looks like an EXCEL formula).

If it is Excel, then you can use the Reverse() function from [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/121618/any-excel-function-that-will-reverse-a-string) and apply it like this:

[image]

Here's the formula:

```
=Reverse(LEFT(Reverse(A1),FIND("/",Reverse(A1),1)-1))
```

Comment: I guess I was thinking backwards. This looks better. +1

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the responses everyone. I should have clarified I'm trying to use this in TIBCO Spotfire. Bascially I'm trying to take an access log file(.txt) and pull the names of the Analyses out of a field, which is a folder path. The function library for 6.5 kinda stinks, and I'm kinda a noob with all this, here are some of the available functions.  [link](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/5.5.0-march-2013/UsersGuide/ncfe/ncfe_text_functions.htm)

Comment: @T-Mc, I would definitely edit your post and specify Spotfire, and remove the reference to SQL. You won't get appropriate answers if you don't tag appropriately and specify the platform in your request. I've edited your tags (removing SQL and adding Spotfire).

Comment: Thank you @rwking, I will definitely work on being more accurate in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Another additional approach using **`PARSENAME()`** function

```
DECLARE @String NVARCHAR(100)
SET @String = '/Applied Analytics/URMFG/Service Analysis/ServiceAnalysis'

SELECT  PARSENAME(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@String, 2, 100), '/', '.'), 1) AS [4th part],
        PARSENAME(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@String, 2, 100), '/', '.'), 2) AS [3rd part],
        PARSENAME(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@String, 2, 100), '/', '.'), 3) AS [2nd part],
        PARSENAME(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@String, 2, 100), '/', '.'), 4) AS [1st part]
```

output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL Statement worked for me in T-SQL 2017:

```
SELECT RIGHT([Filename], CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE('\' + [Filename])) - 1)
```